# CURLOPT_HEADER is not returning all http cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

First of all I'm using codeigniter and used PhilSurgeon codeigniter-curl: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-curl

I'm trying to curl and get the Set-Cookies from the response header from another domain. The code is below

```
$url = 'http://ib.adnxs.com/ptv?id=1403122&size=1x1';

$this->curl->create($url);
$this->curl->http_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8');

$options = array(CURLOPT_HEADER => 1);
$this->curl->options($options);
$vast= $this->curl->execute();

echo "<pre>"; print_r($vast);
```

returns this:

```
Set-Cookie: sess=1; path=/; expires=Fri, 24-May-2013 01:58:10 GMT; domain=.adnxs.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: icu=ChIItcsCEAoYASABKAEwsu_1jAUQsu_1jAUYAA..; path=/; expires=Wed, 21-Aug-2013 01:58:10 GMT; domain=.adnxs.com; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/xml
Set-Cookie: anj=Kfu=8fG1aPCxrx)0s]#%2LcYUiWd4r$[-T_g+2'ti*zYQaYhJGno9P8*w:M5Uy0Hg2:=*oU[fy9; path=/; expires=Wed, 21-Aug-2013 01:58:10 GMT; domain=.adnxs.com; HttpOnly
```

But from this [url](http://ib.adnxs.com/ptv?id=1403122&size=1x1) using firebug you will see there are 4 Set-Cookies header response

```
Set-Cookie:icu=ChIItcsCEAoYBSAFKAUwhND1jAUQhND1jAUYBA..; path=/; expires=Wed, 21-Aug-2013 00:51:16 GMT; domain=.adnxs.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:anj=Kfu=8fG1aPDYS3+0s]#%2LcYUiWd4r$[-T_g+2'thuA$jWEA)yIwtO#ou!><v1GC]*h)%B*hFeR*i`dzw@x-0CY_hN>8<=/=PpF>B2sEM:U9)Egw$gpK<rU3V2sTQBPSK2CBFmAZ4fxWRa/zdHI[^``z>tsw['ZH`CLcww-vV^ufhcR)XmgkjKre#dUU5QfVO.L4fG9GFBu=<jK(f6singv3mi%6gt$7LnUry9e#5x9U`r72%WaCxZpz7-]WIMUV)VDDCc<SUs06To>Gz$A>!A#UF?AH^u[Op<V1s>I#n[aDEPs:sNe8^J#UA<zF-Jik).@gDsrSxfhcQju>xP$yFLD=::tzzS/UTdX!C/=v7)6Fp'>c:%:rUn#/mTw`N#7U9(rwFXkmv^qM'0_QMX_jew(sDj(>a@s0XLV(Y%hCGZ`WDyVH>**Uy08b!:1hy:3!?k; path=/; expires=Wed, 21-Aug-2013 00:51:16 GMT; domain=.adnxs.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:uuid2=3617392369395966810; path=/; expires=Wed, 21-Aug-2013 00:51:16 GMT; domain=.adnxs.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:sess=1; path=/; expires=Fri, 24-May-2013 00:51:16 GMT; domain=.adnxs.com; HttpOnly
```

I'm missing the most important cookie which is the Set-Cookie: uuid2. Is there something wrong with my code on how I curl the url or maybe I'm missing some curl parameter?

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_HEADER sends *all* headers so it will send all cookies. If you get a different set of headers/cookies with curl than with your browser, then it really is because you get a different set!

There can be several reasons to why the set of cookies differs, but the most common reason is simply that the server somehow didn't consider your curl request to be like the browser one so it sends back a different set of cookies for this case. You can often sole that problem by making your HTTP request more similar to the browser requests so make it harder for the server to see a difference.

Comment: tried that, I added http headers on my request but still the same result. I am not able to get the set-cookie uuid2. This is really bugging me. T__T

Answer (score -1):

Looks like that the server requires authorization. All browser's requests (including requests made with Firebug) use a session with authorization flag set. But your script is not authorized (since it uses **another** session), so you get no `uuid2` value.